# Can you pipe a `print()` to ggplot without wrapping it in `()`

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
(
  e <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
    geom_point()
) %>% 
  print()
```

Is there any *"prettier"* way to do this? 'This' meaning print a stored ggplot object. I often have to store plots as an object, yet also want to see them. The `()` wrap really makes things ugly. Seems contrary to core tidyverse principles. I know I could simply call out `e` at the end, but I don't like that either. Something like this is so much cooler. Just look at the difference.

```
library(tidyverse)
f <- mtcars %>% 
  select(cyl) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  print()  # redundant, just proving a point
```

Comment: Does the `%T>%` operator from `magrittr` package do what you want? You'll still have to wrap the ggplot object part in brackets though, since ggplot works with plus rather than pipe operators. `e <- (ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + geom_point()) %T>% print()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is only a matter of consistency with the use of the pipe, you could try the package ggformula that gives access to the features of ggplot2 without the syntax of ggplot2 :

```
library(ggformula)
g <- gf_point(cty ~ hwy, data=mpg) %>% print()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the [package ggfun](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/ggfun) :

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/ggfun")
library(tidyverse)
library(ggfun)

ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() +
  print
```